# googletrans Translate() not working on Spyder but works on Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, google-translate

I am using googletrans Translator on offline data in local repo:

```
translator = Translator()
translations = []
for element in df['myText']:
    translations.append(translator.translate(element).text)
df['translations'] = translations
```

On Google Colab it works fine(20 mins) but on my machine it takes 30 mins and stops with ReadTimeout error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-9-2209313a9a78>", line 4, in <module>
    translations.append(translator.translate(element).text)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 83, in _translate
    r = self.client.get(url, params=params)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 763, in get
    timeout=timeout,

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 601, in request
    request, auth=auth, allow_redirects=allow_redirects, timeout=timeout,

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 621, in send
    request, auth=auth, timeout=timeout, allow_redirects=allow_redirects,

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 648, in send_handling_redirects
    request, auth=auth, timeout=timeout, history=history

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 684, in send_handling_auth
    response = self.send_single_request(request, timeout)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 719, in send_single_request
    timeout=timeout.as_dict(),

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection_pool.py", line 153, in request
    method, url, headers=headers, stream=stream, timeout=timeout

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection.py", line 78, in request
    return self.connection.request(method, url, headers, stream, timeout)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\http11.py", line 62, in request
    ) = self._receive_response(timeout)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\http11.py", line 115, in _receive_response
    event = self._receive_event(timeout)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\http11.py", line 145, in _receive_event
    data = self.socket.read(self.READ_NUM_BYTES, timeout)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_backends\sync.py", line 62, in read
    return self.sock.recv(n)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_exceptions.py", line 12, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from None

ReadTimeout: The read operation timed out
```

My machine: 16 GB Ram (i5 + NVIDIA);
Google Colab RAM: 0.87 GB/12.72 GB

```
# Data Size
len(df) : 1800
```

Not sure why doesn't it run on my local machine? I have worked on heavier datasets before.
I am using Python 3 (Spyder 4.0).

Answer (score 1):

I'm having some problems with this translation as well... It appears that the error you're getting has nothing to do with your machine, but with the request to the API timing out. Try and pass a `Timeout` object from the `httpx` library to the `Translator` builder. Something like this:

```
import httpx
timeout = httpx.Timeout(5) # 5 seconds timeout
translator = Translator(timeout=timeout)
```

You can change to 5 to another value, if needed. It has solver the problem for me, so far.

Comment: I am also facing same issue and tried your solution but again got timeout error. Can you please tell me where should we need to add these two line of code (in starting after the imports or at the end)?