# How to increase the read time using Google trans API?

Tags: python-3.x, google-translation-api

I'm using Google Trans API to translate Million of record in Dataframe. Here is the code I'm using

```
translations = {}
for column in TransEN.columns:
    # unique elements of the column
    unique_elements = TransEN[column].unique()
    for element in unique_elements:
        # add translation to the dictionary
        translations[element] = translator.translate(element,src='pt', dest='en').text
```

Error I'm getting : ReadTimeout: The read operation timed out

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62516992/googletrans-translate-not-working-on-spyder-but-works-on-colab/63743320#63743320